# Deserialize c# class structure containing RootObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net, javascriptserializer

I have a JSON API result that I processed thru an online JSON-to-C# structure program to create the class structure.  I've used this many times for other projects.  The JSON returned everything along with a public class `RootObject` that references both the status and payload segments of the returned values.

I am using ASP.NET C# library to deserialize the result JSON using `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
 var vlist = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TestStruct>(result);
```

My data structure looks like this (it's pretty standard):

```
public class TestStruct
{
    public class Status
    {
        public int statusCode { get; set; }
        public int errorType { get; set; }
        public int errorCode { get; set; }
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payload
    {
        public VehicleStatusRpt vehicleStatusRpt { get; set; }
    }

    public class VehicleStatusRpt
    {
        public string statusType { get; set; }
        //public ReportDate reportDate { get; set; }
        //public VehicleStatus vehicleStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Status status { get; set; }
        public Payload payload { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The full JSON Result I'm trying to parse using the class structure is:

```
{
  "status": {
    "statusCode": 0,
    "errorType": 0,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": "Success with response body"
  },
  "payload": {
    "vehicleSummary": [
      {
        "vin": "KNDJX3AE8E7000080",
        "vehicleIdentifier": "000080",
        "modelName": "SOUL EV",
        "modelYear": "2015",
        "nickName": "My SOUL",
        "generation": 1,
        "extColorCode": "1D",
        "trim": "EV",
        "imagePath": {
          "imageName": "2015-soul_ev-ev-1d.png",
          "imagePath": "/content/dam/kia/us/owners/image/vehicle/2015/soul_ev/ev/",
          "imageType": "1",
          "imageSize": {
            "length": "100",
            "width": "100",
            "uom": 0
          }
        },
        "enrollmentStatus": 1,
        "fatcAvailable": 1,
        "telematicsUnit": 1,
        "fuelType": 4,
        "colorName": "CLEAR WHITE",
        "activationType": 1,
        "mileage": "24410",
        "dealerCode": "MOBISDLR1",
        "mobileStore": [
          {
            "osType": 0,
            "downloadURL": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kia-access-with-uvo-link/id1280548773?mt=8",
            "image": {
              "imageName": "iosImage.png",
              "imagePath": "/content/dam/kia/us/owners/image/common/app/",
              "imageType": "2",
              "imageSize": {
                "length": "100",
                "width": "100",
                "uom": 0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "osType": 1,
            "downloadURL": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myuvo.link",
            "image": {
              "imageName": "androidImage.png",
              "imagePath": "/content/dam/kia/us/owners/image/common/app/",
              "imageType": "2",
              "imageSize": {
                "length": "100",
                "width": "100",
                "uom": 0
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "supportedApp": {
          "appType": "5",
          "appImage": {
            "imageName": "app-access.png",
            "imagePath": "/content/dam/kia/us/owners/image/common/app/access/",
            "imageType": "2",
            "imageSize": {
              "length": "100",
              "width": "100",
              "uom": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "supportAdditionalDriver": 0,
        "customerType": 0,
        "vehicleKey": "937db044-8328-4188-a3d2-68ac3b183752"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I run this thru json2csharp.com to get the structure (the sample above is an abbreviated 'test' only

The deserializer returns an error: Invalid JSON Primitive (starting with Payload)

I see examples of using `RootObject` but with the Newtonsoft JSON libary.  I would like to use the Microsoft library.  Do I really need to switch to Newtonsoft JSON?  If I can use `JavaScriptSerializer` library, how?

Comment: Can you show us the JSON you are trying to deserialize into these classes?

Comment: The full response is:  Oops. too long to paste here.

Comment: I am now using Newtonsoft json.  Still not working correctly.

Comment: Using JsonConvert now.  I see examples using RootObject, but I do not have this library.
Net.Framework 4.5 Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

The classes that correspond to the JSON you posted are:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public int errorType { get; set; }
    public int errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public List<VehicleSummary> vehicleSummary { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleSummary
{
    public string vin { get; set; }
    public string vehicleIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string modelName { get; set; }
    public string modelYear { get; set; }
    public string nickName { get; set; }
    public int generation { get; set; }
    public string extColorCode { get; set; }
    public string trim { get; set; }
    public Image imagePath { get; set; }
    public int enrollmentStatus { get; set; }
    public int fatcAvailable { get; set; }
    public int telematicsUnit { get; set; }
    public int fuelType { get; set; }
    public string colorName { get; set; }
    public int activationType { get; set; }
    public string mileage { get; set; }
    public string dealerCode { get; set; }
    public List<MobileStore> mobileStore { get; set; }
    public SupportedApp supportedApp { get; set; }
    public int supportAdditionalDriver { get; set; }
    public int customerType { get; set; }
    public string vehicleKey { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string imageName { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
    public string imageType { get; set; }
    public ImageSize imageSize { get; set; }
}

public class ImageSize
{
    public string length { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public int uom { get; set; }
}

public class MobileStore
{
    public int osType { get; set; }
    public string downloadURL { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
}

public class SupportedApp
{
    public string appType { get; set; }
    public Image appImage { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to deserialize the JSON just fine using `JavaScriptSerializer` like this:

```
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(result);
```

where `result` is the JSON string you posted in your question.

Note, however, that if you have placed your classes inside another class called `TestStruct` then you would need to take that into account and deserialize to `TestStruct.RootObject` instead, e.g.:

```
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TestStruct.RootObject>(result);
```

I was also able to deserialize the JSON  using Json.Net in the same way with the `JsonConvert` class:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

Once you have the deserialized object, you can extract some interesting information from it like this:

```
foreach (var vs in root.payload.vehicleSummary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} {2} {3}, {4} mi", 
        vs.vin, vs.colorName, vs.modelYear, vs.modelName, vs.mileage));
}
```

Here is a working demo using Json.Net:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zh35be

Comment: Thanks Brian.  This is what I thought would be the solution.  However in my ASP.NET 4.5 project, I awas not able to get RootObject to show as valid! Intellisense didn't show it.  I have "using Newtonsoft.Json;" in the page.  HOWEVER, after I cut and pasted the example you provided, RootObject is now showing in intellisense and as valid.  It appears this is a bug in Visual Studio!!!!